# convertir fecha en milisegundos Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar. Estoy tratando de convertir una fecha en milisegundos,
he realizado en javascript con DATE.UTC

```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_utc

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the numbers of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight January 1, 1970.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var d = Date.UTC(2015, 06, 31);
  console.log(Date.UTC(2015,06,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2015,07,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2015,08,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2015,09,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2015,10,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2015,11,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2015,12,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,01,29));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,02,29));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,03,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,04,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,05,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,06,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,07,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,08,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,09,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,10,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,11,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2016,12,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,01,28));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,02,28));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,03,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,04,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,05,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,06,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,07,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,08,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,09,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,10,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,11,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,12,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,01,28));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,02,28));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,03,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,04,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,05,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,06,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,07,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,08,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,09,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,10,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,11,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2018,12,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,01,28));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,02,28));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,03,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,04,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,05,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,06,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,07,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,08,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,09,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,10,31));
console.log(Date.UTC(2019,11,31));

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

y en SQL Server quisiera que me vote el mismo resultado.

```
SELECT cast(cast(datediff(day, '19700101', dateadd(month,-1,'20150229'))* 24 * 60 * 60 as varchar(250))+'000' as bigint)
```

pero al momento de realizar el numero sale diferente que la función DATE.UTC

Comment: mayúscula == gritar. Edita tu pregunta por favor :D

Comment: @fredyfx Muchas Gracias hermanito, el teclado estaba mal, ya lo he corregido :)

Answer (score 2):

Según leo en la documentación de [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/UTC) el retorno de esta función es el número de milisegundos desde `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, lo cual si pensamos que en un día hay `86400000` milisegundos, estamos hablando de números realmente grandes. SQL Server tiene una función de diferencia que podría sernos de utilidad [`datediff()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), por ejemplo:

```
select DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '19700101', '19700125') as 'ms'

ms
-----------
2073600000
```

Sin embargo, cuando queremos consultar la diferencia un día más, al 26/01/1970 tenemos un simpático `overfow`:

> Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The datediff function resulted in
>   an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two
>   date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less
>   precise datepart.

Esto ocurre por que según la documentación de [`datediff()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the
>   specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate
>   and enddate.

Es decir el retorno es un entero con signo, que en SQL Server es representado por un dato de 4 bytes, siendo [sus límites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) a 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647), limites insuficientes para lo que buscamos.

#### ¿Que alternativas tenemos?

**1. Si tienes SQL Server 2016 o superior**: puedes aprovechar [`datediff_big()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que es capaz de retornar un valor `bigint` un entero de 8 bytes cuyos límites son: -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) a 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807):

```
select DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND, '19700101', '20200313') as 'ms'

ms
-------------
1584057600000
```

**2. Si tienes una versión anterior a la 2016**: La solución ya te la han dado en las otras respuestas y pasa por calcular la diferencia con una magnitud mayor, convertir esta en un `bigint` para luego multiplicarla por los milisegundos. Como tus fechas, no parecen tener la parte horaria, es algo más simple, podemos calcular primero la diferencia en días y ya sabemos que un día tiene `86400000` milisegundos:

```
select CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, '19700101', '20200313') AS BIGINT) * 86400000 as 'ms'

ms
-------------
1584057600000
```

Answer (score 1):

Salvo las fechas, que no encajan con un valor real, como puede ser las que corresponden a los dias 31 de los meses de abril, junio, septiembre y noviembre, puedes aplicar esta solución.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (FECHA DATE)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (FECHA)
VALUES
('20150630'),
('20150731'),
('20150831'),
('20150930'),
('20151031'),
('20151130'),
('20151231'),
('20160129'),
('20160229'),
('20160331'),
('20160430'),
('20160531'),
('20160630'),
('20160731'),
('20160831'),
('20160930'),
('20161031'),
('20161130'),
('20161231'),
('20170128'),
('20170228'),
('20170331'),
('20170430'),
('20170531'),
('20170630'),
('20170731'),
('20170831'),
('20170930'),
('20171031'),
('20171130'),
('20171231'),
('20180128'),
('20180228'),
('20180331'),
('20180430'),
('20180531'),
('20180630'),
('20180731'),
('20180831'),
('20180930'),
('20181031'),
('20181130'),
('20181231'),
('20190128'),
('20190228'),
('20190331'),
('20190430'),
('20190531'),
('20190630'),
('20190731'),
('20190831'),
('20190930'),
('20191031'),
('20191130');

SELECT CAST( DATEDIFF(SECOND,DATEFROMPARTS (1970,01,01),T.FECHA) AS bigint)*1000
 FROM @TABLE T
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontre ese ejemplo:

```
select cast(Datediff(s, '1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE()) AS bigint)*1000
```

y otro más facil todavia:

```
select Datediff_big(MS, '1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE())
```

`Datediff_big` se dedica principalmente con milisegundos y me parece mejor entre esos, porque no se necesita ninguna otra calculacion. Solo diferencia es, que la funcion `Datediff_big` solo existe en versiones 2016 arriba.

Mis ejemplos son del sitio:

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169643/convert-sql-server-datetime-to-milliseconds-since-1970